# Why are ASP.NET settings not showing up when I use ServerManager to create site in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

When I create my site using ServerManager for some reason the asp.net settings are not showing up in IIS, but if I manually create the site and point it at the directory everything works fine a I get all the settings. I have been searching for hours trying to figure out what I am doing wrong with no luck.

Here is my code

```
int sleep = 3000;

Console.WriteLine(@"Installing Connections AD Sync UI\Services...");

//Extract Files
Console.WriteLine(@"Extracting required files...");
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(info.DirectoryName + @"\Payload.zip", ConnectionsADSyncInstaller.Properties.Resources.ConnectionsADSync);
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(info.DirectoryName + @"\Payload.zip", info.DirectoryName);
File.Delete(info.DirectoryName + @"\Payload.zip");

Thread.Sleep(sleep);


//Create IIS Site/Settings
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
Console.WriteLine("Setting up IIS application pool...");
ApplicationPool myApp = iisManager.ApplicationPools.Add("ConnectionsADSync");
myApp.
myApp.AutoStart = true;
myApp.ManagedPipelineMode = ManagedPipelineMode.Integrated;
myApp.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "V4.0";
myApp.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.ApplicationPoolIdentity;
myApp.Enable32BitAppOnWin64 = true; //unsure...
Console.WriteLine("Configuring ConnectionsADSync web site in IIS...");

iisManager.CommitChanges();
Thread.Sleep(sleep);



//Give AppPool user permissions
Console.WriteLine("Configuring folder permissions for IIS application pool...");
DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(info.DirectoryName + @"\ConnectionsADSync\ConnectionsADSyncWeb");
DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"IIS APPPOOL\ConnectionsADSync", FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, AccessControlType.Allow));
myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);

Thread.Sleep(sleep);

//Create the site
Site newSite = iisManager.Sites.Add("ConnectionsADSync", info.DirectoryName + @"\ConnectionsADSync\ConnectionsADSyncWeb", 8089);//D:\\ConnectionsADSync
newSite.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = "ConnectionsADSync";
newSite.ServerAutoStart = true;

iisManager.CommitChanges();
Thread.Sleep(sleep);

//Install Service
Console.WriteLine("Installing ConnectionsADSyncService (Windows Service)...");
Process proc = Process.Start(info.DirectoryName + @"\ConnectionsADSync\ConnectionsADSyncService\installer.bat");
proc.WaitForExit();
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("~ConnectionSyncServer");
service.Start();

Thread.Sleep(sleep);


Console.WriteLine("Installation complete, press Enter to exit");
Console.ReadLine();
enter code here
```

Comment: So it looks like its because its not setting the correct .Net framework version

Comment: you failed to even set the proper application pool. Check my updated answer for more details on how to use the API.

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationDefaults` is not the right place to set the pool for your web site.

Find the root application from `Site.Applications` whose path is "/" and then set its `ApplicationPoolName` to the pool you created earlier.

That can help you associate the proper application pool and it will work just like what you created in IIS Manager.